# call static void

Tags: android

How do I call my function?

```
public static void dial(Activity call) 
{ 
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL); 
   call.startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Obviously not with:

```
dial(); /*Something should be within the brackets*/
```

Comment: Try to pass `this` as argument (provided you start from an Activity of course)

Comment: dial(this); works. Like Anakin said: ITS WORKING!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass null. You have to send a context object.

Where is your function located? If it's inside an Activity or the such, simply pass "this" as the parameter.

If it's inside an BroadcastListener, or a Service, just change the parameter to Context and pass "this".

Comment: What if i call it from another class? Lets say the class with the function is named Action. I know I cant do this: Action.dial(this);

Comment: @Patrick Well it's pretty common to pass the Context around when you invoke methods e.g. calling a utility class. But since you always start executing your logic from an Activity or BroadcastListener or Service, and those are all Context subclasses, you always have something to work with.

Answer (score 2):

You should try
    `ClassName.dial();`

The reason is that static methods belong the class itself, not to an individual instance of it. The call to `instance.dial()` is legal, but discouraged.

Comment: ClassName.dial() doesn't work for me because of "Activity call"

Ive tried ClassName.dial(null) and ClassName.dial(call) aswell.

Comment: @Patrick and what issues do you get? Normally, both your approaches should at least compile. The call with "null" will throw a NullPtrException

Comment: Both do compile, but I get "force close" when I run the application :D

Comment: I would look at the LogCat output for the Exception thrown. If this does not clarify the issue, you might also add a logger statement to check on the Activity, or to add a breakpoint at your call and step the method through.

Answer (score 1):

you should use your ClassName.StaticMethod.... to call a static method of a class

Answer (score 0):

What exaclty is the Problem?

If you've got a class like

```
public class Test {
    public void nonStaticFct() {
        staticFct();
    }

    public static void staticFct() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Works perfectly (even if you should call static functions always by Classname.FctName (`Test.staticFct()`)

I guess the problem here is the missing argument.

[Edit] Obviously I am wrong, according to the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-137265.html#587) you may use a Classmethod by simply calling it, without using the classname (even if it seems odd, since I would expect an implicit this.staticFct() - but possibly the Java compiler is smart enough)